# BASH printf numbers with 1 char suffix

Tags: bash, numbers, format, printf

I'm trying to format a number in BASH. I'd like to replicate the byte/packet number output from iptables.

here are some examples:

```
258
591K
55273
37G
22244
2212
6127K
12M
114K
```

As you can see:

- there is no thousands separator,
- the field is a max of 5 characters wide,
- each suffix is either: none, K, M, G, etc...

I've searched the documentation on printf but have been unable to find anything that can format a number this way. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the input numbers for each of these outputs? Why are some values larger than 1024 not shortened to K versions?

Comment: That is the default format for iptables when viewing the rules. But a full byte count can be found with [iptables -vnxL INPUT] for example. As to why not all are converted? Don't know. If I had to guess, I'd say the original programmer wanted to give as many digits as possible upto 100,000. Then (because field is only 5 chars wide) convert with a single char suffix. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a custom formatting with `awk`, something like this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ u[0]=""; u[1]="K"; u[2]="M"; u[3]="G"} { n = $1; i = 0; while(n > 1000) { i+=1; n= int(n/1000) } print n u[i] } '
```

---

Input sample :

```
258
591000
55273
37000000000
22244
2212
6127000
12000000
114000
```

Output :

```
258
591K
55K
37G
22K
2K
6M
12M
114K
```

Comment: Thanks quantdev, another nice solution - that's a great one-liner! I'll test it and see if it suits. :)

Answer (score 0):

has to be done programmatically, but it's not hard

```
#!/bin/sh
humanFormat() {
    test $x -gt 1000000000 && x=`expr x / 1000000000`G
    test $x -gt 1000000 && x=`expr x / 1000000`M
    test $x -gt 1000 && x=`expr x / 1000`K
}
```

(edited to fix execution order)

Comment: Don't use `expr`. `x=$((x / 1000)K`/etc. Also the order of your statements here will evaluate badly and your second test expressions will explode on the non-numeric values you are assigning to `x`.

Comment: Oops, right you are about the order, I noticed it as I was typing it, then got distracted.  I used expr because I write /bin/sh cripts, not /bin/bash scripts.

Comment: From everything I've read only *very* few (non-posix) versions of `sh` (and derivatives) don't understand arithmetic context.

Comment: Good work, Andras. I like that one. :) I'm guessing though that this is not a built-in feature of printf? I'll test this out and see how it manages with my numbers. :)